# vue unit test with jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I was using jest for my web-app unit testing,but got an tough case.
I import a component in a test.spec.js file , this component imports a http request function from another file , this http request function use the var I defined in the vuex state,and this state data use the window object, which cause the test file error.Here's some codes.

**test.spec.js:** imports a component called Info.vue

```
import Info from '@/pages/user/Info.vue'
```

**Info.vue:** imports a http request function `requestData` from `get-api-data.js`

```
import { requestData } from '@/service/get-api-data'
```

**get-api-data.js:** imports the store(vuex) data

    `import store from '@/store'`

**store** have those vars which involve the window object:

```
env: {
    apiUrl: window._env.apiUrl,
    name: window._env.user,
    password: window._env.apiKey
},
```

and the test suite fails to run.
here's the error:
[image]

Comment: where do you set `window._env` variable?

Comment: I put it in a single file using (function(){})() and include it in index.html.

Comment: so you don't have `_env` variable in window, try to import this file to your test file

Comment: yes, I manage to make it , but got another issue , ```Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined```

Comment: where is this error? please provide more info, i don't see any code where `toLowerCase` used

Comment: the error is from Jest. I use the mint-ui as the ui lib for my project and I import `MessageBox` in a component and when jest parse this component and read the MessageBox import , it crashed and showed : `     TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` and  point to `import { MessageBox, Indicator } from 'mint-ui'`